# global variable (although defined) errors out as not defined in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a rather weird problem in python: I am trying to run this script (it is auto generated using [MMddn](https://github.com/microsoft/MMdnn), which converts one neural network model to another - but this background is irrelevant to this question - just an FYI):

> https://zerobin.net/?a8436f2ae6791499#dhZsFWXc91YpvlHajIqLY74MdeP8pE98E3IELiAD3bw=

but when I execute (using another script which calls this script) it I get:

```
  File "/home/foo/ve_name/env_name/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 550, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/foo/ve_name/env_name/etc/model-r100-ii/pytorch.py", line 288, in forward
    self.minusscalar0_second = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.from_numpy(__weights_dict['minusscalar0_second']['value']), requires_grad=False)
NameError: name '_KitModel__weights_dict' is not defined
```

I am perplexed why this is happening. I can clearly see the __weights_dict being defined globally, so I am clueless why this error appears :(

Any directions to solve this problem would be incredibly useful (wasted 8 hours on this already!)

Comment: Note that double-underscore variables inside classes are name mangled to be "private", *even when they are not class/instance variables*. Using ``__weights_dict`` inside ``KitModel`` is *not* the global ``__weights_dict``, but ``_KitModel__weights_dict`` instead.

Comment: If this is autogenerated code, the question is then though whether you need to fix the output or the generator. Why does the code generator create invalid code in the first place?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: firstly, thank you for your suggestions. From what I understand, and from the autogenerated code, `__weights_dict` is initially defined outside the class and then it is declared as global within the class. So, `_KitModel__weights_dict` is now a global variable. But then why does it complain that it is not found? :( I am confused now! do you have any suggestions on what I can try?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: the code is actually auto generated with mmdnn(https://github.com/microsoft/MMdnn). Perhaps it is a bug, but I am unsure..

Comment: @MisterMiyagi is correct. If you replace `__weights_dict` throughout the file with `_weights_dict` (single leading underscore), it will work.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: to answer your question, I was hoping to fix the auto generated code.

Comment: Python has [name mangling for private variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables), which means *inside a class* every name starting with two underscores is renamed to be exclusive to the class. So using the name ``__weights_dict`` at class scope and at global scope refers to separate variables.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: that solved this problem (but it looks like I have another problem now - but thats not related to this!). Thank you. Could you please post this as a solution and I will accept it? Thanks again. never knew about name mangling.

Comment: @JohnJ Done. I've opened [a pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/MMdnn/pull/863) which should fix the issue in the future.

Comment: oh wow ty for the PR :) @MisterMiyagi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has [name mangling inside class scopes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables), which means that names starting with two underscores are renamed. Inside the class scope, `__weights_dict` actually refers to `_KitModel__weights_dict`, i.e. not the name of the global variable.

As a fix, rename all occurrences of `__weights_dict` to `_weights_dict`.